# Azure upload-batch returning an empty array

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a automation pipeline that needs to target a specific folder in my git hub, run some `sed` commands and when that is done, push everything to an azure blob storage.

here is how my yaml file looks like.

```
yaml template.
parameters:
  client_email: ''
  url_deployment: ''
  storage_account: ''
  working_dir: ''

- task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      AzureSubscription: 'my-azure-resource-manager'
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        source='${{ parameters.working_dir }}'
        echo "SOURCE: "$source
        az storage blob upload-batch --source '${{ parameters.working_dir }}' --destination '$web/' --account-name ${{ parameters.storage_account }} --pattern '[!dist&&!.git&&!.idea&&!client_pipeline.yaml&&!client_template.yaml&&!README.md]*'
```

In my actual pipeline, I set all the variables as follow:

```
variables:
  - name: storage_account
    value: <my-storage-account
  - name: client_email
    value: <my-email>
  - name: url_deployment
    value: <url-deployment>
  - name: working_dir
    value: <my-github-working-dir>

steps:
  - template: client_template.yaml
    parameters:
      client_email: ${{ variables.client_email }}
      url_deployment: ${{ variables.url_deployment }}
      storage_account: ${{ variables.storage_account }}
      working_dir: ${{ variables.working_dir }}
```

When I run this pipeline, everything works just fine. but in my `AZURE_CLI` task, the authentication happens, I can see that I am inside my azure subscription, but than it return just an empty array. like this:

```
WARNING: There are no credentials provided in your command and environment, we will query for the account key inside your storage account. 
Please provide --connection-string, --account-key or --sas-token as credentials, or use `--auth-mode login` if you have required RBAC roles in your command. For more information about RBAC roles in storage, visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli. 
Setting the corresponding environment variables can avoid inputting credentials in your command. Please use --help to get more information.

[]
```

The WARNING, happens all the time, but I was able to push my repo folder to my storage without any problem, this start happening when I refactored my code to be able to have a template to reuse.

Comment: I came across to the problem. The issue is related to the `--source` for some reason it accept only `.` if I pass a variable or a folder name, it stops working. In my case I would like to upload `only` the `workingDirectory` and ignore everything else. I tried to use `--pattern` but I have no idea how to explicitly set it to target only the working directory.

Comment: Could you please try to run the commend line in your local machine and check if this issue still happens? And if it is possible, could you please try to use the real source directory instead of the parameters to try again.